# How to save the data into File in java?

Tags: java, file-io, io

I have one problem, that is I have one string of data and I want to save it into a separate file every time. Please give me a suggestion.

Thanks,
vara kumar.pjd

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: I don't know but it is a common question with lots of examples on the web.

Comment: Unless it's a duplicate, it's a legitimate question. You never know, this may *become* the number one hit on Google for this problem.

Comment: @Peter -- haha I know, just proving a point.

Comment: @Jeremry, using random files names is definately different. ;)

Comment: @Peter: Hope this is not about my answer?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I can confirm this is the #1 result on google for "java store file"

Comment: @kyle Also for "saving data in a file java"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a timestamp in the filename so you can be sure it is unique. Below example uses a timestamp in milliseconds which should be enough in most cases.

If you expect you can have multiple files within 1 millisecond then you could do something with a GUID/UUID. Note that GUID/UUID could result in duplicates too, however this chance is extremely rare.

```
import java.io.*;
class FileWrite 
{
   public static void main(String args[])
  {
      try{
    // Create file 
    FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(System.currentTimeMillis() + "out.txt");
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
    out.write("Hello Java");
    //Close the output stream
    out.close();
    }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
      System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What if he tries to write several file within one step of the granularity of System.currentTimeMillis()?

Comment: Don't think that is likely, if it is than he should add a random number to it or just check if the file exists and add a incremented number.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to compute the filename by yourself, have a look at [File.createTempFile](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29).

From the javadoc:

> Creates a new empty file in the specified directory, using the given prefix and suffix strings to generate its name. If this method returns successfully then it is guaranteed that:
>
> 1. The file denoted by the returned abstract pathname did not exist before this method was invoked, and
> 2. Neither this method nor any of its variants will return the same abstract pathname again in the current invocation of the virtual machine.
>
> This method provides only part of a temporary-file facility. To arrange for a file created by this method to be deleted automatically, use the deleteOnExit() method.

Answer (score 3):

A one liner. Using base 36 for the ids will make the file names shorter.

IOUtils.write(text, new FileWriter(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis(), 36)+".txt")));

http://commons.apache.org/io/

Comment: @Jeremy, thank you for the link. http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ioutils might have benn enough. ;)

Answer (score 1):

One solution can be, use a random number generator to generate a random number. Use this random number with some text as a filename. Maintain a list of already used names and each time you are saving the file, check through this list if the file name is unique.

Comment: Won't the filesystem keep a set of file names created. ;)  Could use File.exists()

Comment: Your general approach is correct. Usually you would have to maintain a set of previous values. Its just in this specific case....

Answer (score 1):

One of possible ways to get *File* object with unique name could be:

```
public static File getUniqueFile(String base, String ext, int index) {
    File f = new File(String.format("%s-%03d.%s", base, index, ext));
    return f.exists() ? getUniqueFile(base, ext, index + 1) : f;
}
```

*Update*: and here goes basic usage/test case:

```
    String s = "foo string\n";

    FileWriter writer = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        File f = getUniqueFile("out", "txt", 0);
        try {
            writer = new FileWriter(f);
            writer.write(s);
            writer.close();
            writer = null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }
    }

    if (writer != null) { try { writer.close(); } catch (Exception e) {} }
```