# writing string into a file in j2me

Tags: java-me

I have a string received  from server(j2me application ). I want to write this string into a file which i have to dynamically create.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save the data into File in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499562/how-to-save-the-data-into-file-in-java)